# Wordpress redirect to splash page once a day for the first week

Tags: redirect, login

How can I redirect the user to the splash page for the first week they ever visit only? This code would redirect it once every week, but I'm more after a once a day for 7 days solution:

```
function checkAccessed(){
if ( !isset($_COOKIE['accessed']) ) { 
    setcookie('accessed', 'yes', time() + 3600*24*7); 
    define("ACCESSED", false);
}else{
    define("ACCESSED", true);
}
}
add_action("init", "checkAccessed");
```

The splash page should permit the user to go to the home page between other links.

Comment: Define `First Week` Please..

Comment: Edited to "First week they ever visit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with Two Cookie.

1. Saves the unix time of user visits first time. Expiration time set to a higher value, [A cookie that never expires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/550907).
2. Set another cookie that is valid for 24 hours.

### Code

```
function wpse144762_check_accessed(){

    if( !isset($_COOKIE['first_time']) ) {
        // user visiting for the first time
        setcookie('first_time', 'yes', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10); // expires in 10 years 
        define("ACCESSED", false);
    }elseif ( 
                !isset($_COOKIE['accessed']) 
                && intval($_COOKIE['first_time']) > time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 
    ) { 
        setcookie('accessed', 'yes', time() + 3600*24); 
        define("ACCESSED", false);
    }else{
        define("ACCESSED", true);
    }
}
add_action("template_redirect", "wpse144762_check_accessed");
```

*Code is not tested. But this should give you the idea*